# Django ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using django with postgresql, whenever I try to save or delete anything, this error occurs -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
self.finish_response()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
Not Found: /favicon.ico
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
[02/Aug/2016 18:30:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2044
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
self.stdout.write(data)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[02/Aug/2016 18:30:14] "GET /api/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 1712)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
self.finish_response()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
self.send_preamble()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
self.stdout.write(data)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\socket.py", line 593, in write
return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
self.handle_error()
File "C:\Users\sushant\Desktop\projects\drfapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 92, in handle_error
super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
self.finish_response()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
self.write(data)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
self.send_headers()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 628, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "C:\Users\sushant\Desktop\projects\drfapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 99, in __init__
super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\socketserver.py", line 684, in __init__
self.handle()
File "C:\Users\sushant\Desktop\projects\drfapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 179, in handle
handler.run(self.server.get_app())
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
self.close()
File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\Lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

What happens is whenever a database save\delete command is there, it gets executed twice, first time without errors, second time, throwing this error and hence, save is done twice.

What I understand is some program is blocking it(as the error says) so I removed the anti-virus that I had but with no conclusions.

Does anyone have any idea what this is all about?

**Edit**: It's a Python bug, reported [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue27682)

Comment: You might check your Windows event log - It looks like something is slaying your open connection so it can't properly send the response to the browser, or whatever you're connecting with. You may also try using `requests` to automate it and see if you can get any more information that way.

Comment: I can't find anything in event log

Answer (score 2):

I have checked in a fix for this in Python: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713

It will be available in the next version of Python 3.7 and later.

Comment: I am using python 3.7.2 but still facing same issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: NEXT version of 3.7. Your version was released Dec. 24, 2018.

Answer (score 1):

I was making a web application and was facing the same issue in windows 10, python 3.7.6, django 3.0.8. I tried a lot of stuff and i finally found a fix.

I was using a form which called a js function onsubmit which in turn sent a REST call which was getting canceled with the '[WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine' error in command prompt.

I added the parameter method='post' and used jQuery.ajax in the js function and i added the event.preventDefault() as well in the function as well as some success and fail callbacks. I don't understand why but now i am not getting the error.

Hope this help anyone using js along with HTML forms until a the issue is root-caused and fixed.

This [Github bug](https://github.com/django-helpdesk/django-helpdesk/issues/621) is tracking the issue

Answer (score 1):

> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

If you are working with the videos this happens when you make another request while the video is uploading to the database.
I would suggest you to use preload='none' in video tag or block the new requests while video is uploading.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this error even with Python 3.6.5 and django 2.0

I noticed 301 redirects in the network tab of the browser debugger. When I fixed them by appending trailing backslashes to all url/api calls in my html/js, this problem went away. The urlconf must have trailing backslashes as well.

Comment: could you give an example for this?

Comment: I tried appending slashes, and it still gives me the error.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me in the past:
In my case:
I opened it in firefox first and faced this error.
then I opened it in Microsoft edge and the error was gone.
try this:
open the server URL in a different browser, and see the result must be normal.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same error: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053].
Python version: 3.8.1

I restarted my computer and the error disappeared

Comment: I was restarting my computer, too, until I discovered it was caused by having more than one tab open in my browser with my django app running.