# getting this error " ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

**When I type "dir" in the console I receive this error and the error shows this line " client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")"  **

```
def socket_accept():

conn, address = s.accept()
print("Connection has been established | " + "IP " + address[0] + "| Port " + str(address[1]))
send_commands(conn)
conn.close()


def send_commands(conn):

while True:
    cmd = input()
    if cmd == 'quit':
        conn.close()
        s.close()
        sys.exit()
    if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
        conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
        client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
        print(client_response, end ="")
```

Comment: in http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472876/why-is-host-aborting-connection is exactly the same behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is host aborting connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472876/why-is-host-aborting-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link - it says upgrade python to 3.7.3 or higher version:

> [Django ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab)