# Django Closed Socket Error with Repeated AJAX Calls [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, ajax, django, jquery-select2, django-wsgi

I'm trying to implement a live search through the jquery plugin Select2 in my Django 1.11.4 project. Running Python 3.6. When I type in the textbox, the server doesn't seem to be able to handle the number of requests and it closes, followed by these series of errors.
I've spent a couple hours following a couple threads on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab) [SO(more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab) , [Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/Cps4kHh0_-0), [etc](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/wsgiref-When-does-the-complexity-of-question-require-posting-to-the-Developers-or-other-forums-td5204605.html) but none have a working solution. I thought it was a python version issue, but I've upgraded from 2.7 to 3.6 and still have it. Any help would be great thanks!

This the view that's being called by the ajax call:

```
  def directory_search(request):
      # Query text from search bar
      query = request.GET.get('q', None)
      if query:

          # Searches the DB for matching value
          customers = Customer.objects.filter(
              Q(name__icontains= query)|
              Q(contract_account__icontains= query)|
              Q(address__icontains= query)|
              Q(address__icontains= query)|
              Q(email__icontains= query)
              ).distinct()
          # Turns queryset into dict
          customers = customers.values("contract_account","name")
          # Turns dict into list
          customers_list = list(customers)

          return JsonResponse(customers_list, safe=False)
      else:
          return JsonResponse(data={'success': False,'errors': 'No mathing items found'})
```

This is the js/ajax call for the Select2 plugin:

```
  $(".customer-search-bar").select2({
    ajax:{
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      url:"{% url 'portal:directory_search' %}",
      data: function (params) {
          var queryParameters = {
              q: params.term
          }
          return queryParameters;
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
          return {
              results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                  return {
                      text: item.name,
                      id: item.contract_account
                  }
              })
          };
      }
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection,
    language: { errorLoading:function(){ return "Searching..." }}
  });
```

Errors:  (I just broke them apart to make it more legible, but they occurred in the presented order)

1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

2.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\leep\PythonStuff\virtual_environments\rpp_3.6\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 88, in handle_error
    super(ServerHandler, self).handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

3.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\leep\PythonStuff\virtual_environments\rpp_3.6\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 155, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\leep\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that its a python 2.7 known bug, maybe it remains on python 3.6:

https://bugs.python.org/issue14574

I'm having a similar issue in django, also running python 3.6
[TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable followed by AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355998/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable-followed-by-attributeerror-n/46474637#46474637)

**Edit**

It seems to be a error on chrome. It didn't come to me, 'cause I was using Opera, but opera uses chromium as well. In internet explorer the error didn't show.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21227#no1

This is the bug tracker