# Django making a many post requests to a another webapp always cancelled

Tags: python, django

I creating a website (for practice only) that allows user to check the Name of their favorite artists and my website will show details about that artists

I created a form with textarea and once the user Submit all their favorite artist ( POST Requests to other path of my webapp ), It cancelled and return a error on terminal

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "F:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[24/Jul/2019 00:18:58] "POST /knowers/parser HTTP/1.1" 200 322
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "F:\Python\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "F:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ConnectionAbortedError: \[WinError 10053\] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab)

Comment: The error is not helpful, possibly due to the bug mentioned by @ThatBird above. Please post the code for your view handling the POST to /knowers/parser.

Comment: evrythin is now ok, I just update the python to the latest