# django: Getting error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' even when I am able to access the page

Tags: python, django

I am getting below error while running command. However, page is opening but on command prompt below error is coming. I referred other stackflow pages where similar error is there but it didnt helped.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Error:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 19, 2019 - 13:04:14
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'first_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[19/Dec/2019 13:04:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2786
[19/Dec/2019 13:04:19] "GET /static/css/mystyle.css HTTP/1.1" 200 68
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[19/Dec/2019 13:04:19] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2211
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
[19/Dec/2019 13:04:19] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52848)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\rishbans\Anaconda3\envs\DjangoProject\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any idea, where I should look into it. Let me know if you need any specific file.

Comment: The main error you should be googling for is `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`

You can start here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab

Comment: @MKaras above link didnt solve the issue. I am using python 3.7.2.

Answer (score -1):

This simply means that `self.status` is somehow returning a **None** value. So insert a check and try like this:

```
if self.status != None:
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0]
```

Comment: In which file and what purpose it will solve.

Comment: split just makes a list of a given string. It cannot make a list of a None type object. So just replace your line with the above mentioned one because it'll atleast check if your object is not None

Comment: @KKimash you may want to learn and read a traceback. This error is in wsgiref\simple_server.py (Python's stdlib code), and it's actually only the consequence of _another_ issue.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Got it! Is it okay to sat that it is the consequence of _another_ issue because the traceback points to a standard file right ( that comes preinstalled with Django )? If it were pointing to a file that the user himself has created, then would we have changed the code itself?