# Django local host connection aborted

Tags: python, django

I am having new issue when running Django localhost 127.0.0.1:8000 as connection getting aborted
,this is new for me as I am working with Django from 3 month and cant find solution for it.

below is the Exception i got:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 50501)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yazan Bader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Yazan Bader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Yazan Bader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Yazan Bader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Yazan Bader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\Yazan Bader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

any help pls?

Comment: thanks for replying, unfortunately no.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab

Comment: still same, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

issue solved and its cause one static file with .mp4 type is causing the browsers to block connection I remove it and everything works fine.