# how can fixed this problem: ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: python, django, hosting

after install django when will start browsing at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ then this massage will show in powershell.

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 3575)
[06/Feb/2020 09:48:03] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85876
[06/Feb/2020 09:48:03] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 85692
[06/Feb/2020 09:48:03] "GET /static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff HTTP/1.1" 200 86184
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\fuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "c:\users\fuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "c:\users\fuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Fuel\.virtualenvs\sample-DQH4k00R\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Fuel\.virtualenvs\sample-DQH4k00R\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "c:\users\fuel\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

this is the photo:
[ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWNGU.png)

how can i fixed it?

Answer (score -1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721428/django-connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-ab) link on another stack Overflow link, is it possible you are using an outdated version of Python? It was reportedly fixed 2019-07-22 according to [python's bugs website](https://bugs.python.org/issue27682)